# packaging and running a third party installer with my install4j installer

Tags: install4j

Sorry for asking a question so similar to the last install4j question, but I have a similar problem. I need to package third party installers with my install4j installer that need to run before my application is installed. I'm currently unable to host the other packages, so the only option I see is to package them with my installer. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add the third-party installers on "Installer->Custom Code & Resources"
2. Add "Run executable" actions in your installer and reference the third-party installers with `${installer:sys.resourceDir}/executable.exe`